# Bash: How to check for first three characters in a file

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

After some string conversion of heterogeneous data, there are files with the following content:

file1.txt:

```
mat 445
```

file2.txt:

```
mat 734.2
```

and so on. But there are also intruders that do not match that pattern, e. g.

filen.txt:

```
mat 1
FBW
```

With everything that starts with "mat" I would like to proceed while all other lines shall be deleted.

The following does not work (and seems rather ponderous):

```
for f in *.txt ; do
     if [[ ${f:0:3} == "mat" ]]; then
           # do some string conversion with that line, which is not important here
           sed -i -e 's/^.*\(mat.*\).*$/\1/' $f
           sed -i -e 's/ //g' $f
           tr '.' '_' < $f
           sed -i -e 's/^/\<http:\/\/uricorn.fly\/tib\_lok\_sys\#/' "$f"
           sed -i -e 's/\(.*\)[0-9]/&> /' "$f"
     else
           # delete the line that does not match the pattern
           sed -i -e '^[mat]/d' $f
     fi
done
```

As the comment below shows the if condition is incorrect as it does not match the file's content but its name.

Desired output should then be:

file1.txt

```
<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#mat445>
```

file2.txt

```
<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#mat734_2>
```

filen.txt

```
<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#mat1>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You are absolutely right that there are occurances of mat 1 e or mat 1 (2), but I thought I could deal with that later and hopefully on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Source data, with some extras added to the last 2 files:

```
$ for s in 1 2 n
do
    fn="file${s}.txt"
    echo "+++++++++++ ${fn}"
    cat "${fn}"
done
+++++++++++ file1.txt
mat 445
+++++++++++ file2.txt
mat 734.2.3
+++++++++++ filen.txt
mat 1 2 3
FBW
```

One `awk` solution that implements the most recent set of question edits:

```
awk -i inplace '                                                # overwrite the source file
/^mat/ { gsub(/ /,"")                                           # if line starts with "^mat" then remove spaces ...
         gsub(/\./,"_")                                         # and replace periods with underscores
         printf "<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#%s>\n", $0     # print the desired output
       }
' file{1,2,n}.txt
```

**NOTES**:

- the `-i inplace` option requires `GNU awk 4.1.0` (or better)
- remove comments to declutter code

The above generates the following:

```
$ for s in 1 2 n
do
    fn="file${s}.txt"
    echo "+++++++++++ ${fn}"
    cat "${fn}"
done
+++++++++++ file1.txt
<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#mat445>
+++++++++++ file2.txt
<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#mat734_2_3>
+++++++++++ filen.txt
<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#mat123>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed:

```
sed -ri '/^mat/{s/[ ]//g;s/[.]/_/g;s@^(.*)$@<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#\1>@g}' *.txt
```

Search for lines starting with mat and then first remove spaces, replace . with _ and finally substitute this string with a string including the http string prepended.

Comment: This is almost perfect. Unfortunately, this version does not replace the original line but writes it additionally.

Comment: You mean it doesn't amend the original file?

Comment: Try the sed alternative

Comment: The awk command creates the string but does not transform the string according to the sed and tr commands given in the example above: For file2.txt the string dot should be converted to an underscore. So

awk '/^mat/ { print "<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#"$0">"  }' $f > $g

creates

<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#mat734.2>

instead of

<http://uricorn.fly/tib_lok_sys#mat734_2>

Comment: OK. the sed solution has been amended

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are far more elegant, but none worked on my system so here is what did eventually:

```
for f in *.txt ; do

    # Remove every line that does not contain 'mat'
    sed -i '/mat/!d' $f

    # Remove every character until 'mat' begins
    sed -i -e 's/^.*\(mat.*\).*$/\1/' $f

    # Remove the blank between 'mat' and number
    sed -i -e 's/ //g' $f

    # Replace the dot in subcategories with an underscore
    tr '.' '_' < $f

    # Add URI
    sed -i -e 's/^/\<http:\/\/uricorn.fly\/tib\_lok\_sys\#/' "$f"
    sed -i -e 's/\(.*\)[0-9]/&> /' "$f"

    uniq $f
```

done